# Returning output value from JavaScript code in Java using Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

I have this short code here

```
 ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        String foo = "print(2);";

        Object s =engine.eval(foo);

        System.out.println(s); // printing null
```

What i am trying to achieve is that i want the result that engine.eval(foo) will print to save it in a string variable example s value should be 2 , how can i realize it in this case that engine.val(foo) is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is that Javascript's `print()` function is not returning a value (in TypeScript it would be `function print(): void`). So your code works just fine (you can actually see `2` being printed in stdout) but the return value of `print(2);` which is `void` is interpreted as `null`.

If you invoke a function (or a statement) that *returns* a value, it will work just fine:

```java
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        String foo = "x = 1+2;";

        Object s = engine.eval(foo);
        System.out.println(s); // printing 3
```

You can also use variables to handle results:

```java
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        String jsCode = "jsVar = 1+2;";

        engine.eval(jsCode);
        Object javaVar = engine.get("jsVar");

        System.out.println(javaVar); // printing 3
```